# How to add locales in Craft 3

Tags: localization, craft3

I'm getting started with Craft, using version **3 beta**, and I don't find the menu option for adding locales so I guess it's not yet ready but there must be another option.

Could anyone guide me through the process of creating a multi-language **Craft 3** site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Sites" in Craft 3 replaces the old "Locales" concept in Craft 2.

There's not much [documentation](https://github.com/craftcms/docs#core-concepts) on them yet, but the [setup process](https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide) is virtually the same as it is in Craft 2 for locales.  The main difference is that a "site" isn't necessarily tied to a language code, like it is in Craft 2.

https://craftcms.com/news/craft-3-multi-site

> **Update**: [Localization docs for Craft 3](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/localization.html)

Comment: Definitely, this answer pointed me in the right direction. Thanks.
I am adding a **very useful** Hangouts where they explain step by step how to do this: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_Yqwvx-gA0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_Yqwvx-gA0)

Answer (score 2):

Documentation has been added for this: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/localization.html